# Edits to a post to provide a snippet, but the snippet doesn't work

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, stack-snippets

I found an edit to a [post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15578446/1714488) on the 4th Feb this year.

To be honest, there wasn't anything wrong with the post (other than a cheeky response/salutation, which I've now removed), but the user deemed it necessary to downvote it, edit it and edit the code to include a link to the external file... Fair game, *but* the resulting snippet didn't work, so I'm trying to figure out the point of the edit - other than the user meeting some form of goal!? I've just rolled it back and largely because, if the snippet doesn't work, then it's an instant negative for anyone visiting the post.

I don't mind anyone editing any question or answer I've ever written, but are there guidelines (anywhere) on ideal snippet-building? In this case it failed miserably IMO.

Comment: With the experience the editor has, the edit was a genuine attempt to improve the post.  You can always roll an edit back if you don't like it.  Or if the snippet doesn't work, you could fix it (while keeping the other changes), remove the part that doesn't work, or ping the user to point out that it doesn't work (or ask why they made the edit they did).  The downvote likely came from another user that saw the post on the recent activity page.